# How to rotate an array right

Tags: java, arrays, rotation

I have wrote a program to shift an int array left, but cannot find a way to move it right. Could you take a look at my code and comment if you have any ideas how how to "rotate" my array right based on the number of spaces (int x), as currently it only moves left. Thanks

```
public void makeRight(int x) {
   int[] anArray = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   int counter = 0;
   while (counter < x) {
        int temp = anArray[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length - 1; i++) {
            anArray[i] = anArray[i + 1];
         }

         anArray[anArray.length - 1] = temp;
         counter++;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++){
      System.out.print(anArray[i] + " ");
  }
}
```

Comment: It currently moves it right, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Rotate an array right

```
public void makeRight( int x )
{
    int[] anArray =
    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int counter = 0;
    while ( counter < x )
    {
        int temp = anArray[anArray.length - 1];
        for ( int i = anArray.length - 1; i > 0; i-- )
        {
            anArray[i] = anArray[i - 1];
        }
        anArray[0] = temp;
        counter++;
    }
    for ( int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++ )
    {
        System.out.print( anArray[i] + " " );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (counter < x) {
    int temp = anArray[anArray.length - 1];
    for (int i = anArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        anArray[i] = anArray[i - 1];
    }
    anArray[0] = temp;
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion basically you had done on most of the parts to rotate an array (right).
Just that the concept of

> `anArray[i] = secondArray[(i + x) % anArray.length];`

And

> `anArray[(i + x) % anArray.length] = secondArray[i];`

is a bit different.

There would be something like this

```
    int[] anArray = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    //int counter = 0;
    //int x = 2;
    int[] secondArray = new int[anArray.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++) {
        secondArray[(i + x) % anArray.length] = anArray[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < secondArray.length; i++){
        System.out.print(secondArray[i] + " ");
    }
```

As for how the "%" works, [Codility - CyclicRotation](https://matoski.com/article/codility-cyclic-rotation/) this link should had a clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
    private void shiftArrayRight() {
        int endElementvalue = element[element - 1];
        int[] startElements = Arrays.copyOfRange(element, 0 , element.length - 1);
        element[0] = endElementvalue;
        for(int i = 0, x = 1; i < startElements.length; i++, x++) {
            element[x] = startElements[i];
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(element);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below function can help you

```
public static void rightRotateArray(int[] a, int requiredIterations) {
  // right-rotate [a] by k moves
  // totalActiveIterations  by MOD 
  // => because every n(a.length) rotations ==> we receive the same array
  int totalActiveIterations = requiredIterations % a.length; 
  for (int i = 0; i < totalActiveIterations; i++) {
   // make lastElement as BKP temp
   int temp = a[a.length - 1];
   // make other elements => each one equal previous one [starting by lastElement]
   for (int j = (a.length - 1); j >= 1; j--) {
    a[j] = a[j - 1];
   }
   // make 1stElement equal to (BKP as temp = lastElement)
   a[0] = temp;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are merely code dumps, with zero explanations. Here's an algorithm I came up with:

We rotate the array in place. Observe that the target position of every element is given by `(index + k) modulo size`. For range `0` to `k - 1`, we recursively swap each element with the one in its target position as long as the target position is greater than the current position. This is because since we are incrementally progressing from lower to higher indices, a smaller target index indicates that the corresponding element had already been swapped.

```
Example:
Rotate [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] by 3

Index to target index:
0 to 3
1 to 4
2 to 5
3 to 0
4 to 1
5 to 2

swap(0, 3) => [4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6]
swap(0, 0) => return
swap(1, 4) => [4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6]
swap(1, 1) => return
swap(2, 5) => [4, 2, 6, 1, 2, 3]
swap(2, 2) => return

Done!

Another example:
Rotate [2, 3, 4, 1] by 1

Index to target index:
0 to 1
1 to 2
2 to 3
3 to 0

swap(0, 1) => [3, 2, 4, 1]
swap(0, 2) => [4, 2, 3, 1]
swap(0, 3) => [1, 2, 3, 4]
swap(3, 0) => return

Done!
```

**Code:**

```
static void rotateRight(int[] xs, int k) {
        swap(0, 0, xs, k);
}

private static void swap(int original, int current, int[] xs, int k) {
    int target = (original + k) % xs.length;

    if (target > current) {
        int tmp = xs[current];
        xs[current] = xs[target];
        xs[target] = tmp;

        swap(target, current, xs, k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<int> rotateLeft(int d, List<int> arr)
{
    int listSize = arr.Count();
    int[] newArr = new int[listSize];
    
    for(int oldIndex=0; oldIndex< listSize; oldIndex++)
    {
        int newIndex = (oldIndex + (listSize - d))% listSize;
        newArr[newIndex] = arr[oldIndex];
    }
    List<int> newList = new List<int>(newArr);
    return newList;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code and why the code in the question was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to use c++ 11 and above, in Codility test for Cyclicrotation.
imagine doing it in earlier versions, Duh!

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
vector<int> solution(vector<int> &A, int K) {
 if (A.size() == 0) {
        return A;
    }

    for (int i=0;i<K;i++) {
        //Create auciliary array
        std::vector<int> aux(A.size());
        //copy array to be rotated there by means of C++11
        std::copy(std::begin(A), std::end(A), std::begin(aux));
        //insert last element from aux to begining of the array
        A.insert(A.begin(), aux.end()-1, aux.end());
        //remove last element which is already become first
        A.pop_back();
        
    }
    return A;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change the code like this

```
public void makeRight(int x) {
int[] anArray = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int counter = 0;
while(counter< x){
       int temp = anArray[anArray.length - 1];
        for (int i = anArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            anArray[i] = anArray[i - 1];
        }

        anArray[0] = temp;
        counter++;
 }
for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; i++)
System.out.print(anArray[i] + " ");
}
```